# Object Session not being passed

Tags: php, session, object

On File A.php I have a while Loop that pulls data from a database and connects to class.php to create objects for each dataset.  That part works fine.
Within that Loop I try to save each object to a SESSION defined by its id value
after New Object has been created

File A.php:

```
$_SESSION[$pObject->id] = $pObject;

if (isset($_SESSION[$pObject->id]))

{

echo "SESSION $pObject->id is set"; 

}
```

I have confirmed that it IS being created.

NOW, I have a form that sends an Objects id value via a GET to File B.php, I have confirmation that the value is received.

File B.php:

```
require_once 'class.php';

session_start();

$id = $_GET['id'];

echo $id;

//Now $id is in my new file, so I try to call my SESSION

if(isset($_SESSION[$id]))

{

echo "SESSION $id is set";

$pObjectCurrrent = $_SESSION[$id];

}

else{

echo "SESSION $id is Not set";

}
```

The issue is, that despite `$id` in File B.php being equal to the value of `$pObject->id` in File A.php the `SESSION[$id]` in File B.php is NOT set and has no value.  Instead I receive an undefined variable error.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `session_start()` in file a as well ?

Comment: file A.php is "included" in a main.php which has a session_start()

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what's actually in there and if the `$id` really is the same as `$pObject->id`.

Comment: var_dump($SESSION[$pObject->id] in File A Confirms pObjects id is equal to $id in File B, However var_dump($_SESSION[$id]) in File B resulted in "NULL"

Comment: is the session_start being called before the include and not after ?

Comment: apologies, it is a require once not an include I typed that wrong, the session_start is located after the require once for the class.php

Comment: It needs to be located before `class.php` is required so the session can be started. Since `class.php` appends data to the session array you need to start the session before it does this.

Comment: the session_start has to be after the included classes, else the object stored in the session becomes undefined and unusable

Comment: But the included class manipulates the session as well right, or am i misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an integer as your session variable name.

You could set the session var like this:

```
$_SESSION['obj' . $pObject->id] = $pObject;
```

Then retrieve it from B.php like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['obj' . $id];
```

Essentially that concatenates the ID with a string so the variable name would be "obj5", "obj2", etc.

Also - if you're passing a lot of data in session objects, I'd recommend researching serializing and alternatives like storing session data to DB.